# A completely reducible module is Artinian if and only if it is Noetherian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, noetherian, artinian

> Suppose that $M$ is a completely reducible module over a ring $R$, that is, 
>   $$M=\bigoplus_{\alpha\in J}M_\alpha$$ 
>   where each $M_\alpha$ is an irreducible $R$-module (irreducible means it has no proper non-trivial submodule).
>
> Prove that $M$ is Artinian if and only if it is Noetherian.

This is Problem 7 (on page 122) of $\S$3.5 in Jacobson's *Basic Algebra II* (2nd edition). Jacobson earlier proves the following characterisation of completely reducible modules (on page 121), but I am not able to see how to use it.

> **Theorem 3.10.** *The following conditions in a module $M \neq 0$ are equivalent:*
>
> 1. *$M = \sum M_\alpha$, where the $M_\alpha$ are irreducible.*
> 2. *$M$ is completely reducible.*
> 3. *The lattice $L(M)$ of submodules of $M$ is complemented, that is, for every submodule $N$ of $M$ there exists a submodule $N'$ of $M$ such that $M = N \oplus N'$.*

Any hints on how to solve this? Some intuition also?

Comment: what is the definition of completely reducible module?

Comment: @Sky It is a direct sum of irreducible modules.

Comment: irreducible means indecomposable?

Comment: @sky irreducible is stronger: an irreducible module has no proper non-trivial submodules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $M$ is either Artinian or Noetherian,then the index set $J$ is finite.every irreducible module is Noetherian and Artinian.